# Getting Errors With Nether Gem When Deploying On Heroku

Tags: heroku, rubygems

I've been using Nether for endless page on my app and it works great localy, but when I deploy to heroku and try to render a view where there is a controller method with 'nether' in it I get this error in the logs

←[36m2013-06-09T20:20:33.091413+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/resources" for 176.61.88.70 at 2013-06-09 20:20:33 +0000
←[36m2013-06-09T20:20:33.253704+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2013-06-09T20:20:33.253704+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m NoMethodError (undefined method `nether' for #):

How can I make Nether available in Heroku ie. find the 'nether' helper?
Here is the Gem
https://github.com/maecro/nether
The 'nether' method is in app/helper/nether_helper and I think its path is defined in lib/nether/engine

I realise there is a similar issue that was resolved in the latest version 
https://github.com/maecro/nether/pull/4
but this does not solve it for me

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION FOUND. Using the most recent version of the gem change every instance of nether in the controller actions to render_nether. Heroku can't find the gems' helper method(nether) but can find the controller method(render_nether). No need to change the nether call in the views.